# How to access Serial port variable in another file of the project?

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a C# project, and in my MainWindows.cs I have a function that creates that sets up the serial communication via a COM port. I want to access this variable in another file from the same project, but I can't seem to do it. The GUI is a WPF app using .NET framework.

```
public void init() //function that creates the BT connection, it is in the MainWindows.cs
{
     SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();
     myPort.PortName = "COM8";
     myPort.BaudRate = 9600;

     try
     {
          myPort.Open();
          myPort.WriteLine("Connected");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

And this is the function in which I'm trying to access the **myPort** variable, but it does not work.

```
private void running() // This function is in an another file, called Patient_list.cs, which has its own XAML file.
{
      string alert;
      alert = myPort.ReadLine(alert); //Error: The name "myPort" does not exist in the current context
      int to_int = Int32.Parse(alert);
      if (to_int == 2)
      {
            status.Text = "Level 2";
            status.Foreground = Brushes.Orange;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating "myPort" as a **local** variable at the init function.
Doing it that way, you'll not be able to get access to it from the other file.

A possible solution, is declaring myPort as **global**.
Then, inside the file where you have located the function running(), you can do an instance of the file containing that global variable using this line of code:

```
var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

So, merging this solution to your function, it would look like this:

```
private void running() // This function is in an another file, called Patient_list.cs, which has its own XAML file.
{
  var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
  window.myPort // Here you can take its value.
}
```

See: [Difference between local and global variables](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-local-and-global-variables/)